# Objective C / Solving math systems

Tags: objective-c, xcode, math, computational-geometry

I've been trying to develop a simple app that calculates the equation of a curve using information given by the user.

For example, let's suppose the user has the equation of a circle and the equation of an ellipse, and he wants to know the intersection points.
Mathematically speaking, this is a quite simple problem, but i can't figure out how to tell Xcode to solve that system.

I've looked into the Accelerate framework, and i found the "dgesv" function of Lapack. This would be a perfect solution for a system of lines, but what about more complex systems like the one i've stated before?

I was even wondering how to calculate the tangent line of a curve, and other similar geometry problems.

Comment: the **[Numerical Mathematics](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sugexp=cappsweb&gs_rn=8&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=JS67SfvrWUsfC88d_-oHAg&cp=15&gs_id=1m&xhr=t&q=numerical+mathematics&es_nrs=true&pf=p&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=numerical+mathe&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44990110,d.Yms&fp=256fd6e963ae561b&biw=1848&bih=948)** would have been a useful subject at the university. it could help you, if you dig yourself into.

Comment: Analytically it might be rather complex to solve non-linear problems, but numerically it becomes easier. If you have had experience before with Bisection or Newton-Raphson numerical methods then you know what you need to do but are unclear on how.

Comment: Look up Groebner bases and Buchberger's algorithm.  (I'd have included links, but markdown really seems to hate me at the moment.)

Comment: upvoted the question but downvoted the 2 answers as they are overly broad for a quite specific question (how to have the set of solutions to a system of non linear equations). Happy to remove my downvotes if specifics are given! I only know how to get a single solution (like any non linear optimization does), but not the whole intersection subspace between N non linear equations.

Comment: (although if you have a single solution to the problem, you might find a tangent vector that preserves the solution, and walk along this path, if you know it is expected to be a curve).

Comment: Well, the question is not all that specific, as it does not specify exactly what curves are to be considered (only gives circle and ellipse as an example). This is pretty complicated to solve in general, so you probably want to handle things in a somewhat case-by-case manner (or you can try to find a library that suits your needs... probably not so easy either). Maybe you can try to describe in more detail what types of curves you want to handle?

Answer (score 0):

> For example, let's suppose the user has the equation of a circle and the equation of an ellipse, and he wants to know the intersection points. Mathematically speaking, this is a quite simple problem, but i can't figure out how to tell Xcode to solve that system.

The problem of intersecting a circle and an ellipse in general involves solving a fourth degree polynomial equation. You can break it down to third degree, but square roots alone won't suffice. So I'd say that's not really a “quiet simple problem”. That being said, some numeric libraries do support algorithms for finding the real or complex roots of a univariate polynomial. So you'd eliminate one of your variables (e.g. using resultants or Gröbner bases) and then feed the resulting polynomial to that. Not sure what libraries would be most suitable in the Objective C world. But a question asking to suggest a specific library would be deemed off-topic anyway, so use the keywords I mentioned to find something that suites your needs.

> I was even wondering how to calculate the tangent line of a curve, and other similar geometry problems.

The tangent direction is simply orthogonal to the gradient of the implicit form. In other words, describe your curve not parametrically as x=f(t) and y=g(t) but instead implicitely as f(x,y)=0. In case of a circle that would look like *x*<sup>2</sup>+*y*<sup>2</sup>+*ax*+*by*+*c*=0. Then compute the partial derivatives with respect to *x* and *y*. That's 2x+a and 2y+b. So (2x+a, 2y+b) is perpendicular to the circle, and (2y+b, -2x-a) is tangential. Not sure what you'd consider similar to this.